# Saving pdf from R-Shiny only generates a temporary pdf

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, pdf-generation

I am writing an r-shiny app that takes user input and outputs it into a formatted pdf report. I can get the pdf to generate but its a temporary file (with a randomly generated temporary name) and I am not given an option to save it unless I save it from the pdf viewer itself. When the user pushes the 'Download Report' button I want them to be able to pick where the file is saved as I will eventually make this mobile compatible and it will need to work on laptops/phones/tablets etc. Not sure if it is related but any files that get copied to the temp directory (i.e rmarkdown files or images) need to be in the same folder as the Shiny App.

What do I need to change to make it save to the local computer? There are no errors or warnings produced when I execute the code just something like:
Output created: C:\Users\SGrass\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsrlxyW\file32a43867233b.pdf

Even when I try running the example from here I get the same issue (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html)

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
  downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server = function(input, output) {
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
    filename = "report.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed).
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(n = input$slider)
      
      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, 
                        output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: pdf_document
params:
  n: NA
---

```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$n
```

A plot of `params$n` random points.

```{r}
plot(rnorm(params$n), rnorm(params$n))
```
````

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66056764/knitr-cannot-find-pdflatex-when-creating-pdf-from-shiny-app) might be helpful.

Comment: While the file.rename(out,file) was missing, once added it still generated the temp file with no option to save locally

Comment: See the answer [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1285#issuecomment-374340175)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue. It seems that post had two issues, one with tinytex and one with spaces in the file output name. I have neither of those issues. The pdf gets generated properly. The issue is that it won't give the option to save it and just generates with a temporary name instead of the name specified in output_file